# Symfony use entityManager in some Class

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How can i get the entityManager in some classes in Symfony ?
Tried to add a service but entityManager is null ... 
What is the best way to do this in Symfony 4 ?

It's for call a function in a Repository from another class.

Answer (score 3):

To access the entityManager inside your Service, you have to construct it first.

```
namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class ServiceName
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
    public function myFunction()
    {
        $classRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ClassName::class);
    }
}
```